# Can I get a menu item for Pastebin in Files?

Tags: pantheon-files, extensions

In nautilus there is `nautilus-pastebin`.

> nautilus-pastebin is a Nautilus extension written in Python, which
>   allows users to upload text-only files to a pastebin service just
>   by right-clicking on them.

---

[image: Imgur]

---

Is there any such feature in elementary OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nautilus and Files do not share any code. Any extensions written for Nautilus are not compatible with Files.

There is a package called "[webcontracts](https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+recipe/webcontracts-daily)" that provides Pastebin through a system service called Contractor among other things. You can download a .deb from the link or install through the [unstable daily PPA](https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily).

Comment: The status of `webcontracts` is in development, can I install it? If so, how to install? will you please add to your answer. :)

Comment: @Ravan You can do whatever you'd like :p Keep in mind that nobody has touched this code since 2012 though. It's more a proof of concept than anything.